# SSRS Report Different queries based on a parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is it possible to choose different queries based on a parameter in SSRS? I have 5 different queries and i want to choose one of them. I dont want to merge these queries via using "Union".  All of the queries have the same fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I am not completely sure but it should be possible.  Go to Report Dataset Properties (View > Report Data > Datasets > ReportDataSource > Right click - Dataset Properties).  In the Query > stored procedure name field - you should be able to specify an expression.  Click on "Fx" button and write expression.  Sample given below.

=IIF(Fields!Param1.Value = "x", "SP1", "SP2")

Answer (score 0):

you can use union in the below way:

```
select ... where 1 = param 
union 
select ... where 2 = param 
union 
select ... where 3 = param 
union 
select ... where 4 = param
```

passing param values 1 will only pull results from first query and similarly for 2,3 and 4. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I cant use Union, because when i use it, the execution plan will be the same for each query.